# Creating Objects exclusively with Factory

Tags: java, object, factory

I'm currently working on a student project and wondering if there is a way to create objects exclusively with factory methods?

```
public class PersonFactory {

    public static Person createPerson() {
        // some constraints ...
        return new Person();
    }

}
```

My exemplary `PersonFactory.java` is supposed to return `Person` objects with its `createPerson()` method.

```
public class Person {

    // some examples ...
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This works fine, but in the `main` program, I am still able to create `Person` objects with their common constructor (since it is `public`). But if I change the constructor to `private`, the factory method cannot access it either.

```
public class PersonManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // both still works ...
        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = PersonFactory.createPerson();
    }

}
```

Thank you so much in advance ;)

Comment: Notice that Factory pattern doesn't force you to use a Factory Class. Defining a private constructor and using a factory method (i.e. getInstance()) that could be implemented or overridden by a child class is also a valid use of the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually solve the problem by putting the factory method in the `Person` class rather than in a separate factory class. In this case the constructor can be private, and `Person` objects can be obtained from the factory method and nowhere else. Don’t know whether that could fit into your design, though.

One potential issue here would be if you didn’t want your factory method `static`. However, I see that yours is, so this shouldn’t stop you.

Comment: Note that you can get around the `static` issue by making the factory class a public, static, inner class in the target class, and giving the factory class a public instance method.

Answer (score 7):

You can make the `Person` constructor package private (i.e. remove the `public` access modifier), which will only allow classes from the same package to access it.

Then, if `PersonFactory` belongs to the same package as `Person`, it would have access to that constructor.

If `PersonManagement` belongs to a different package, it won't have access to that constructor.

Another option is to keep the `Person` constructor `private` and move the `createPerson()` method to the `Person` class.

Answer (score 1):

With the visibility concept of Java, there is not much you can do. You can remove `public` from the `Person` constructor, then only these classes in the same package of `Person` (and subclasses of `Person`) can access the constructor. If `PersonManagement` is in another package, it will not be able to access the constructor.

Another way would be to make Person to an inner class of PersonFactory (or the other way around), then the private constructor should work, too, and noone outside of the outer class will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, this one pretty much solved my problem:

```
public class Person {

    // some examples ...
    private String name;
    private int age;

    private Person() {
    }

    public static Person createPerson() {
        // some constraints ...
        return new Person();
    }

}
```

And the `main` works pretty fine as well:

```
public class PersonManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = Person.createPerson();
        // not possible anymore ...
        Person p2 = new Person();
    }

}
```